# On the construction of the Chevalley isomorphism

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

I am currently trying to get an better understanding of Grothendieck's simultaneous resolution given by
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\tilde{ \mathfrak{g}} @>{\theta}>> \mathfrak{H}\\
@V{\pi}VV @VVV\\
\mathfrak{g} @>{\phi}>> \mathfrak{H}/W
\end{CD}
With $\mathfrak{g}= \operatorname{Lie}(G)$ for a semisimple linear algebraic group $G$ with fixed Borel subgroup $B$ and $\tilde{\mathfrak{g}} = \{(x,b) \in \mathfrak{g} \times G/B ~\vert ~ x \in b \} $. $W$ the Weyl group and $\mathfrak{H}$ the "abstract Cartan subalgebra" that is the quotients $b/[b,b]$ for Borel subalgebras $b$ canonically identified by conjugation with elements  in G. The map $\theta $ is then simply the projection $(x,b) \mapsto x ~\operatorname{mod}~ [b,b] \\$  
I am personally not quite sure about the Chevalley isomorphism $\phi$. I am familiar with the Chevellay Restriction theorem $ \mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g} ]^G \cong \mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{h} ]^W  $ and the proof given in e.g Humphreys Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory (Chapter 23.1). Now it is said that $ \mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{h} ]^W \cong \mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{g} ]^G \to \mathbb{C} [\mathfrak{g} ]$ yields a morphism on varieties $\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{h}/W$, but sadly, I am not sure how this is done. I suspect that I want to identify the spaces with the maximal ideals in the correponding algebras, as I am working over an alg. closed field, and obtain $\phi $ by taking preimages. but I am not quite sure whether this would result in this commutative diagram, or if this would commute at all. 
I am thankful for any help someone might provide.

Comment: Chevall(e)y with an (e)...

Comment: This is Lemma 3.1.42 in Chriss-Ginzburg, which also includes a few pages earlier the enlightening example of $\mathrm{SL_n}(\mathbb{C}$, where the map $\phi$ essentially sends a matrix $x\in\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ to the unordered tuple of its eigenvalues. Proving the diagram commutes goes as you suspected; as you want to know that two morphisms into an affine variety are equal, it suffices to consider the corresponding diagram of rings of global functions. By the way, Chriss-Ginzburg make a distinction between the Weyl group realized as a subquotient of $G$ and the ``abstract Weyl group"

Comment: that acts on $\mathfrak{H}$. (Note that $\mathfrak{h}$ and $\mathfrak{H}$ are different, and the definition of the map $\phi$ passes through both, because the Chevalley restriction theorem is about restricting to an actual subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ of an actual Borel subalgebra $\mathfrak{b}$. The algebra $\mathfrak{H}$ isn't in any sense contained in any of the Borel subalgebras of $\mathfrak{g}$.